# MongoDB stores data only to primary shard in case choosing tagging shard key

Tags: mongodb, sharding, database, nosql

I'm using mongodb v3.0 and trying to make sharding with tagging shards.
Documentation [mongodb v3.0 documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/) shows how to configure it.

I have 2 shards:

```
mongos> sh.addShardTag("shard0000", "USA")
mongos> sh.addShardTag("shard0001", "EU")
```

and collection for sharding is test_collection:

```
mongos> db.printShardingStatus()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
 "_id" : 1,
 "version" : 3,
 "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
 "currentVersion" : 4,
 "clusterId" : ObjectId("555df7f4f6506e6ba07e1f20")
}
  shards:
 {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27017",  "tags" : [  "USA" ] }
 {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27018",  "tags" : [  "EU" ] }
  databases:
 {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
 {  "_id" : "test_collection",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
```

As you can see in this case it chooses shard0000 as primary.
When I've tagged collection and enabled collection for sharding:

```
mongos> sh.addTagRange("test_collection.items", {country: "USA"}, {country: "USA"}, "USA")
mongos> sh.addTagRange("test_collection.items", {country: "EU"}, {country: "EU"}, "EU")
mongos> db.runCommand({shardCollection: "test_collection.items", key: {"_id": "hashed"}})
```

and inserted data (about 20K items), I've checked status

```
mongos> db.printShardingStatus()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
 "_id" : 1,
 "version" : 3,
 "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
 "currentVersion" : 4,
 "clusterId" : ObjectId("555df7f4f6506e6ba07e1f20")
}
  shards:
 {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27017",  "tags" : [  "USA" ] }
 {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27018",  "tags" : [  "EU" ] }
  databases:
 {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
 {  "_id" : "test_collection",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
  test_collection.items
   shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
   chunks:
    shard0000 1
   { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 0) 
    tag: EU  { "country" : "EU" } -->> { "country" : "EU" }
    tag: USA  { "country" : "USA" } -->> { "country" : "USA" }
```

So, shard tags were applied, but data were written only to primary shard.

Each step I've made according to manual, so can somebody tells me what I missed in configuration?
Same behaviour shows only in case choosing shard tags. Without tags, e.g. only by shard key it works correctly and data stores to both shards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your shard key is the hashed "_id" column, but you are tagging ranges on the "country" column.

According to the docs this is not possible:

> MongoDB supports tagging a range of **shard key** values

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/

You need to make the "country" column part of your shard key.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Borut!

I've tried actually "country" as shard key, but it also didn't work. Maybe I've made some another mistake in configuration. But after above comment I've repeated all steps and got sharding configuration works correctly.

So, I post below all flow step-by-step to get up the configuration:

- After marking shards with tags (shards already were added) check the status

```js
shardingversion: {
  "_id": 1,
  "version": 3,
  "minCompatibleVersion": 3,
  "currentVersion": 4,
  "clusterId": ObjectId("555df7f4f6506e6ba07e1f20")
}shards: {
  "_id": "shard0000",
  "host": "127.0.0.1:27000",
  "tags": [
    "USA"
  ]
}{
  "_id": "shard0001",
  "host": "127.0.0.1:270001",
  "tags": [
    "EU"
  ]
}databases: {
  "_id": "admin",
  "partitioned": false,
  "primary": "config"
}{
  "_id": "test_db",
  "partitioned": true,
  "primary": "shard0000"
}
```

- Then add shard key to collection we'll use

`db.runCommand({shardCollection: "test_db.items", key: {"country": 1}})`

Note in this case I've chosen key as simple as possible, but in real systems you should choose it more carefully.

Add tag ranges for our shards:
`sh.addTagRange("test_db.items", {country: "MX"}, {country: "USA"}, "USA")`
`sh.addTagRange("test_db.items", {country: "ES"}, {country: "GER"}, "EU")`

```js
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
        "currentVersion" : 5,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("556376557b13cb3ac8b90b49")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27000",  "tags" : [ "USA" ]
}
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27001",  "tags" : [ "EU" ] }

  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "test_db",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
                test_db.items
                        shard key: { "country" : 1 }
                        chunks:
                                shard0000       2
                                shard0001       1
                        { "country" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "country" : "ES
" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(2, 1)
                        { "country" : "ES" } -->> { "country" : "MX" } on : shar
d0001 Timestamp(2, 0)
                        { "country" : "MX" } -->> { "country" : { "$maxKey" : 1
} } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 2)
                         tag: EU  { "country" : "ES" } -->> { "country" : "GER"
}
                         tag: USA  { "country" : "MX" } -->> { "country" : "USA"
 }
```

- Ok, let's add elements to collection

```js
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
{ 
  db.items.insert({"model": "One", "country":"EU"}); 
  db.items.insert({"model": "iPhone", "country": "US"});
}

for(var i=0; i<10;++i)
{
  db.items.insert({"model":"X", "country":"EU"});
}
```

Our expectation is to get 1K elements on one shard and 1K + 10 on second shard.

See the result:

```js
db.items.stats()
{
        "sharded" : true,
        "userFlags" : 1,
        "ns" : "test_db.items",
        "count" : 2010,
        "numExtents" : 6,
        "size" : 225120,
        "storageSize" : 344064,
        "totalIndexSize" : 155344,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 81760,
                "country_1" : 73584
        },
        "avgObjSize" : 112,
        "nindexes" : 2,
        "nchunks" : 3,
        "shards" : {
                "shard0000" : {
                        "ns" : "test_db.items",
                        "count" : 1000,
                        "size" : 112000,
                        "avgObjSize" : 112,
                        "numExtents" : 3,
                        "storageSize" : 172032,
                        "nindexes" : 2,
                        "lastExtentSize" : 131072,
                        "paddingFactor" : 1,
                        "userFlags" : 1,
                        "totalIndexSize" : 81760,
                        "indexSizes" : {
                                "_id_" : 40880,
                                "country_1" : 40880
                        },
                        "ok" : 1
                },
                "shard0001" : {
                        "ns" : "test_db.items",
                        "count" : 1010,
                        "size" : 113120,
                        "avgObjSize" : 112,
                        "numExtents" : 3,
                        "storageSize" : 172032,
                        "nindexes" : 2,
                        "lastExtentSize" : 131072,
                        "paddingFactor" : 1,
                        "userFlags" : 1,
                        "totalIndexSize" : 73584,
                        "indexSizes" : {
                                "_id_" : 40880,
                                "country_1" : 32704
                        },
                        "ok" : 1
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Check "count" fields on each shard statistics.

I hope information above is usefull for those who are fighting with same issue and save your time to find out the solution.